# Tcl dict modify the key name

Tags: dictionary, tcl

Lets say I have a dict `somedict` with `key1 value1`

Is there a way to modify `key1`, let's say, to be `somekey1` without removing `key1` and making a new record for `somekey1` ?

Comment: Do you want to add new record to dictionary?

Comment: No. I just want to rename the key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `lappend` new variable in dictionary and set the value from old variable to new variable then `unset` the old key.

```
set somedict [dict create key1 "black dict" key2 "white dict"]

//dict update somedict key1 varKey1 {
//    dict lappend somedict someKey1 $varKey1
//    unset varKey1
//}
//or 
set rename key1
set to someKey1
set somedict [dict replace $somedict $to {[dict get $somedict $rename][dict unset $somedict $rename]}]

set value [dict get $somedict someKey1]
puts $value
```

Go to [TCL Dictionary](http://wiki.tcl.tk/19938) for more information.

If you're looking for rename variable command there's no such thing in TCL.

Comment: That's what I thought to do also, but thought there could be a more efficient way.

Comment: There isn't a more efficient way; it has to make a new hash entry in the underlying table. Moving the data over is otherwise cheap though; the contents of the entry are transferred by reference.

Comment: Note that this solution as currently stated does not work.

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of the fact that a dictionary is also a list, which is also a string.

Note that I will usually tell you never to mix operations and manifest types (i.e. never use, say, list operations on a string). But just like in music, in Tcl every rule can be broken if you just know what you're doing. (Except for the twelve syntactic rules, those are sacrosanct.)

Given this dictionary:

```
% set somedict [dict create key1 "black dict" key2 "white dict"]
key1 {black dict} key2 {white dict}
```

You can do a string transform:

```
% set somedict [string map {key1 somekey1} $somedict]
somekey1 {black dict} key2 {white dict}
```

And you get a new functioning dictionary:

```
% dict get $somedict somekey1
black dict
```

(The value will briefly be a string value, but it reverts to a dictionary value when you use a dictionary operation on it.)

This is a bit dangerous, though: `string map` will make substitutions on every match it finds, including inside longer strings.

If you know which key you want to change in order, you can use a simple list transformation:

```
% lset somedict 0 somekey1
somekey1 {black dict} key2 {white dict}
```

If you don't know where it is, you can search for it (it better be there though, otherwise `lset` tries to change element -1):

```
% lset somedict [lsearch $somedict key1] somekey1
somekey1 {black dict} key2 {white dict}
```

It's ugly, but it's straightforward.

Documentation:
[dict](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/dict.htm),
[lsearch](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lsearch.htm),
[lset](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lset.htm),
[string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm)